# SQL Server 2014 Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server, ssms

As soon as I log in to my server instance I get :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
(Microsoft.Visual.Studio.Platform.WindowManagment)
```

I tried repairing Management Studio. No result.
Tried repairing the SQL Server instance. Nothing.
Tried repairing *.Net 4 ...  Same thing.

I can not do anything in the Managment studio except run queries.
All of my databases are not shown.

I have an hunch that database mail is malfunctioning but I can not get into 
SQL Server agent to correct the issue (Modify the job). Stopping it makes no difference.

I have seen lots of similar issues here but they do not help me in any way.

How can I get in control of my server instance ? I really don't know what else to do. Is there something I can do apart from reinstalling? I am virtually locked out.

Comment: See if you have the latest Service Pack, updating it might help.

Comment: IIRC the most common cause of this error is using SSMS at a lower version and/or patch level than the SQL Server DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can be caused by so many things that's impossible to find out.
I have narrowed the culprit to corrupt internet explorer installation.
Why it became corrupt I don't know.Maybe some update. I actually almost never used it.
Bottom line, I had to reinstall the windows server and sql server from scratch. 2 days of work.
Thank you Microsoft.